# How to use threading to run the same proccess multiple times with specified data

Tags: python, multithreading, api, download

I want to make a script to download files from links from a text file. It works with this code:

```
import urllib.request
import random
import threading

def request(line):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(line, 'D:\\example_directory\\' + str(random.randint(1000000, 9999999)) + "-69" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + "-" + str(random.randint(1000000, 9999999)) + ".mp4")

with open('D:\\example_directory\\links.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        threading.Thread(target=request(line)).start()
```

This code works, but it doesn't start to download the second link before the first one finished downloading. This is a problem for reasons that dont need to be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the last line with `threading.Thread(target=request, args=(line,)).start()`. In your code the request is executed before the Thread object is even created.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `threading.Thread(target=request(line)).start()`
You can also replace it with `Thread(target=lambda line=line: request(line))`